# Convert a Ruby on Rails project to a JRuby on Rails project

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, rmi, jrubyonrails

is there any particular way to convert a Ruby on Rails project to a JRuby on Rails project?
There now is a need to get the Rails side to talk to a Java server via RMI so was wondering how to make the conversion. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Karl says, it pretty much works but there are a number of caveats you should be aware of:

- The database adapters will be different from the ones you may be used to. They're based on [JDBC](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/database/index.jsp). For example, the MySQL adapter install is described [here](http://blog.emptyway.com/2008/04/08/120-seconds-guide-to-jruby-on-rails/)
- You will generally deploy to Java application servers in production such as [Glassfish](http://glassfish.java.net/), [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/). Typically this is done using [Warbler](http://caldersphere.rubyforge.org/warbler/)
- Certain gems with native extensions may not work. See [here](http://blog.headius.com/2008/10/ffi-for-ruby-now-available.html) for details on the what is required

Comment: Great, thanks, this is what I was looking for. Question though, assuming you want to use both Ruby on Rails an JRuby on Rails for different projects, how do you keep the various similar gems separated?

Comment: @peppermonkey. I would highly recommend the Ruby Version Manager for managing rubies and partitioned gems. See http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/

Answer (score 2):

It pretty much just works, you simply run it with JRuby instead of Ruby.

You might be interested in this though:
http://jrubyist.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/jruby-and-sqlite3-living-together/

Comment: Good to know! Will be using a postgresql database behind the scene as opposed to a sqlite but still good to know. Thanks.