# How to inherit java classes in a Ruby on Rails environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json, api, java

**Background:** I have a Java application that many programming clients interface with. Recently, a few clients wanted me to develop an API to allow them to inherit my application's Java classes in their Ruby documents without having to change their developing environment to Jruby - they want it to remain Ruby on Rails.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357647/how-do-rails-and-jruby-relate/3368322#3368322) post, it was mentioned that this could be accomplished by using XML or JSON as a middle-man between Java and Ruby on Rails.

**Question:** Is the XML/JSON method the best practice? If so, which do you find to be preferable (XML or JSON)? If not, what is a better practice?

Once a best practice is determined, some in-depth (as in-depth as you're willing to go) explanation as to how I should approach this would really be helpful.

Thank you so much

Comment: I don't think you mean inherit? Do you mean reuse the application logic via an API?

Comment: yeah i think that was a poor word choice on my part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML or JSON is really a matter of taste when talking server-level APIs. Both are text formats that can be trasmitted via HTTP, and either one can be consumed by a Rails application.