# Deploy Ruby on Rails in Glassfish

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, glassfish, jruby

I just started to learn Ruby on Rails. Now I created a simple project and it worked fine in IDE (Aptana). My question is: How can I deploy it in Glassfish?

Some online articles mentioned JRuby and some Glassfish Gem, but there's no details on how to do it. Do I have to use JRuby and is there a step by step tutorials that tell me how to deploy my rails project in Glassfish?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use JRuby as Glassfish is a Java EE Application Server.

Here is a tutorial:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19776-01/820-4926/chapterone/index.html

Comment: So can i somehow convert my existing RoR project into using JRuby?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216128/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-project-to-a-jruby-on-rails-project